# Ankhsvn plugin for VS2012 not picking up some dll changes

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I have a solution with several projects under source control (subversion).

When I build the solution, dll's from my projects are dumped in the /bin of the website project, AnkhSVN picks up changes for the most dlls, but some show up as unchanged, and I have to manually right-click them and pick "Add to Pending Changes" option in order to be able to commit them.

Working copy explorer shows dll's as changed (red square next to them), but they are not in the "Pending changes" window.

Any idea on ways of fixing this behavior?

p.s. I'm not interested in "don't version dll's" type of feedback.

Comment: Those dlls are outputs from your own project(s)? If not, how do you proceed to update them?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: updated the question, the dll's are from my projects

Comment: Seems to be a known issue (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=487). I have had the problem but only with images files.

Comment: @cheesemacfly I don't think this is the same issue, in my case file IS marked as modified by Ankh, it just doesn't show up in the Pending Changes list.

Comment: Oooh yes you're right, sorry. And if you use tortoisesvn do you have the same behavior?

Comment: @cheesemacfly no, TortoiseSVN works just fine

Comment: And when you have your "pending changes" window opened (Ctrl+K C) is the "Show all files" on top, next to "show message", available? If yes, is it active?

Comment: @cheesemacfly "Show all files" button is disabled